# DNS issue with domain, NS are not recognized / working

Tags: networking, dns, domain

So I have the teothemes.com domain. I recently moved it to another server. I defined the nameservers at the godaddy interface like this:

And then just changed the nameservers of the domain to ns1.teothemes.com and ns2.teothemes.com

I did the same process for 4 domains and just the parent one isn't working

According to http://www.intodns.com/teothemes.com it says:

> Mismatched NS records      WARNING: One or more of your nameservers did
>   not return any of your NS records. Error  DNS servers responded
>   ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond: The ones that
>   did not respond are:
>   198.89.122.235 198.89.122.236

I have no idea what that means since I did the same process for all the domains and I checked everything like 3 times and it  still won't work.

Any help is appreciated!